# Kerning absent in .ttf and .otf files made with with Fontographer 5

Tags: fonts, typography, kerning

I configured my font's kerning for every possible letter combination in Fontographer 5 and when I preview it from there, everything is as it should be, but when I generate the font files (TTF and OTF) and try using it in a word processor, there is no kerning at all.

Am I doing something wrong?
How can I fix this?

Please help, I've spent days on setting up the kerning.

Answer (score 4):

I found out that there is a huge problem with generating font files that include kerning pairs in **Fontographer 5.0**. As update 5.1 fixes this, downloading the newest update (5.2 currently) from FontLab's website should fix this for You. There is also a kind of experimental solution with instructions available on their forums that You can try if You want to avoid updating but I don't recommend it since it didn't really work for me.

Update - found another solution:
Export the metrics from Fontographer and generate the font,
open the generated font in e.g. FontLab Studio and 
import the metrics,
generate from the second program.

Update 2 - 
You can also send your fog and fea files to support@fontlab.com and they'll fix it if you are unable to do it otherwise